# restrict users from changing certain picklist values, using validation rules

Tags: picklist, validation-rule

I am trying to restrict certain users to restrict changing few picklist values, But they are still able to change the picklist.

```
AND(
    RecordType.Name ='Banker',  $UserRole.Name = 'Executive', ISCHANGED(StageName__c),
    OR(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName__c), 'Reviewing'),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName__c), 'Required Docs')
)
)
```

But the user with Executive Role can still change the stageName picklist to reviewing, can someone let me know where am I going wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validation rule is set up to prevent changing the `StageName__c` field *away from* "Reviewing" or "Required Docs". If you want to impede changing *to* those stages, you don't need `PRIORVALUE()`, which is providing the value of the field prior to the change that's being attempted.

Comment: Ok, so I removed the PriorValue function, but the user can still change the Picklist to Reviewing

Comment: Ahh, this is silly I was entering incorrect Role Name. It is working now!!!
Thank you @DavidReed